# How do I get log4j rolled over log file name or pattern?

Tags: java, log4j

I was able to get the current log file name with this fragment of code:

```
Enumeration allAppenders = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getRootLogger().getAllAppenders();

while (allAppenders.hasMoreElements())
{
   Object appender = allAppenders.nextElement();

   if (appender instanceof FileAppender)
   {
      File logFile = new File(((FileAppender) appender).getFile());
      break;
   }
}
```

But if I have rolled over log files, how do I get their names?

It seems like it's not guaranteed that rolled over log files start with logFile.getName() as its prefix.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shoul check for [org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/RollingFileAppender.html) and/or [org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html) (depending of the kind of rolling you are using) and use their own specific methods, i.e. getDatePattern() for a `DailyRollingFileAppender`

Comment: How about for RollingFileAppender?
It seems like there are no methods I can call.

Comment: I've given a glance to source code of rollOver method of  RollingFileAppender, seems that log4j too _don't know_ the rolled filename :o